# Create multiple histograms for each level of a variable (factor) with scales of each own

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to create 27 histograms of the variable "billed" (numeric, x-axis) for each level of a factor variable "zip" (y-axis is "count").  "zip" has 27 levels.

Is there a way to display 27 histograms on one graph (3X9), no over-laid?

I tried this using ggplot2:

```
p<-ggplot(dat,aes(x=billed))+geom_histogram(aes(fill=zip),binwidth=1.5)
+facet_wrap(~zip,ncol=9)
```

The new problem is all these histograms have the same scale. But my data's y-axis/x-axis vary a lot among different zips. Is there a way to create these histograms based on their own scales?

I don't mind using regular r function if this could also be realized by hist(), since the aesthetic features in ggplot2 are not useful for my case.

Comment: `facet_wrap(~zip,ncol=9, scales="free")`?

Comment: @baptiste  Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(lattice)
histogram( ~ billed | zip , data=dat, 
           layout=c(3,9) , scales= list(y=list(relation="free"),
                                        x=list(relation="free") ) )

 #worked example from ?histogram page:
 histogram( ~ height | voice.part, data = singer, 
            layout = c(2,4), scales=list(y=list(relation="free"),
                                         x=list(relation="free") ) )
```